# Replacing HTML script url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, scripting

I need to replace a url like below :

res.replace('/Kentico9/', 'http://localhost/Kentico9/');

But the res variable contain HTML elements of the entire page, which create issues with escapes. Where the entire HTML element is not considered while replacing.

I have written the above line of code, but its not replacing as expected.

Please help:

Below is the replaced code: But still i can see below line after replacement :

> src="/Kentico9/WebResource.axd?d=
>
> ```
>  <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var theForm = document.forms['form']; if (!theForm) {
> theForm = document.form; } function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
> if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
>     theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
>     theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
>     theForm.submit();
> } } //]]> </script>
> ```
>
> //

Comment: Your snippet is really hard to parse. The `src="/Kentico9/WebResource.axd?d=` seems really out of place - can you show us the actual code? The code snippet doesn't contain Kentico9

Comment: Do you have the same homework as http://stackoverflow.com/q/36619001/7552